# ¿Como soluciono error por restriccion de llave foranea?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo un error en mi base de datos en algunas tablas, estas tienen informacion dentro, el problema esta en que cuando intento eliminar algun dato me salta este error

```
ERROR:  update o delete en «cronograma» viola la llave foránea «fk_participantes_id_cronograma» en la tabla «participantes»
DETALLE:  La llave (id_cronograma)=(3) todavía es referida desde la tabla «participantes».
```

Por lo que entiendo es que un dato sigue referenciado con el de la tabla que quiero eliminar, quisiera saber como se soluciona

Comment: Revisa la tabla, mira como funciona la clave foráanea, a que columna, de que tabla, y elimina ese registro. Con ello no deberías tener mas ese error. Saludos.

Comment: Si elimino el dato al que esta referenciado si me elimina normal, pero ese error me da con varios registros, y no puedo eliminar tantos

Comment: Las columnas de la tabla las tengo con 'NOT NULL', si las cambio a 'DEFAULT NULL' dara el mismo error?

Comment: El problema se debe a la relación que encuentra con otra tabla, es como si tubieras un maestro asignado a un detalle y quieras eliminarlo. En caso de que estes completamente seguro de no necesitar mas esta relación, has lo que te sugiere Randall en la respuesta de el, de lo contrario, debes eleminar esos registros que estan siendo referidos, Saludos.

Comment: Cuidado!, eso no es un error, si no te deja borrarlo de esa manera es para mantener la integridad de la base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que quieres hacer es que al eliminar un cronograma elimine también los participantes lo que se puede hacer es especificar "borrado en cascada" al definir la relación:

```
ALTER TABLE cronograma 
  DROP CONSTRAINT fk_participantes_id_cronograma;
ALTER TABLE
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_cronograma) 
    REFERENCES participantes (id_cronograma)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**Nota:** el nombre de las tablas y de los campos los deduje de tu pregunta, pero podrían ser otros.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas eliminar registro de la tabla `«cronograma»` y en verdad no te afecta la eliminación de la relación que existe entre dichas tablas, lo que debes hacer es eliminar la llave foránea y ahí si podrás eliminar de dicha tabla, sin preocuparte por la relación.

Esta es la sentencia que deberás usar:

```
ALTER TABLE cronograma
DROP CONSTRAINT fk_participantes_id_cronograma;
```